# Yii CArrayDataProvider does not update active page on GridView

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, yii

I'm using **yii bootstrap widgets TbGridView** to view data from my database table.

evry page request I get the data from my **API** using **offset** , and I update the grid view `databrovider` from the result of **API**.

I used **CArrayDataProvider** for that.

my problem is at the first request it return the records and it display all pages on **pagination** on grid view, and when I click on any page on pagination it return the data by offset but the grid view does not add **active class** on the clicked page.

and I was set  **currentPage = 0** in pagination option and if I remove this option and click on any page on pagination it return **no result found**  Although there is a result on my Data Provider

my code is :

this is my data provider

```
$offset = $limit * ($page_no-1) ;
$arr_transaction = $obj_transaction->getTransactionByOffset($offset);
$total_record    = $total_record = $obj_transaction->getTotalRecord();

$dp_transactions = new CArrayDataProvider($arr_transaction,
array('id'=>'transactions',
    'keyField' => false,
    'pagination'=>array(
        'pageSize'=>10,
        'params' => array('date_from' => $transaction_form->date_from,'date_to'=>$transaction_form->date_to),
        'currentPage'=>0,

    ),
    'totalItemCount'=>$total_record,
));
```

and this is my Grid view

```
<?php 

        $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbGridView', array(
            'type'=>'striped bordered condensed',
            'dataProvider'=>$dp_transactions,
            'template' => "{summary}{items}{pager}",
            'enablePagination'=>true,
            'columns'=>array(
                array('name'=>'ust_order_Id', 'header'=>'Oreder Id'),
                array('name'=>'ust_create_time', 'header'=>'Transaction Time'),
                array('name'=>'ust_email', 'header'=>'Email'),
                array('name'=>'ust_mobile_number', 'header'=>'Mobile Number'),
                array('name'=>'ust_amount', 'header'=>'Amount'),
            ),
        )); 
    ?>
```

and I don't need to supply **ALL THE DATA** to the `CArrayDataProvide`.

Any one can help me

Thanks

Comment: when you use **CArrayDataProvider**, you don't need to set offset, grid view will handle that for you

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I don't use offset in CArrayDataProvider , I use offest to get data from my table, so each time CArrayDataProvider will have 10 record only.

Comment: You're setting `'currentPage'=>0,` in the `CArrayDataProvider`....try calculating the current page using the offsets and limits

Answer (score 0):

It is "defect" of `CArrayDataProvider`: Length of your array must be bigger than `(CURRENT_PAGE-1) * PAGE_SIZE`.
So you can pad empty values to your array:

```
$offset = $limit * ($page_no-1) ; // it means $page_no is current page number
$arr_transaction = $obj_transaction->getTransactionByOffset($offset);
$total_record    = $total_record = $obj_transaction->getTotalRecord();

$arr_transaction = array_pad($arr_transaction, -1*(count($arr_transaction) + $offset), null);

$dp_transactions = new CArrayDataProvider($arr_transaction,
array('id'=>'transactions',
    'keyField' => false,
    'pagination'=>array(
        'pageSize'=>$limit, // $limit = 10 ?
        'params' => array('date_from' => $transaction_form->date_from,'date_to'=>$transaction_form->date_to),
        // 'currentPage'=>0, this not needed

    ),
    'totalItemCount'=>$total_record,
));
```